# Samba authentication of user with wbinfo -a

Tags: redhat, samba, ntlm

i setup a RedHat server with samba/kerberos/winbind.

I can retrieve my user and groups with wbinfo -u and wbinfo -g.
BUT in the listings, the name appears like that :

```
wbinfo -u 

DOMAIN+username1
DOMAIN+username2
DOMAIN+username3
DOMAIN+username4
```

If i try to authenticate a user with `wbinfo -a username1%password` i've got this error :

```
plaintext password authentication failed
error code was NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER (0xc0000064)
error messsage was: No such user
Could not authenticate user username1%password with plaintext password
challenge/response password authentication succeeded
```

If I put the domain into the username it works :

```
wbinfo -a DOMAINE+username1%password 

plaintext password authentication succeeded
challenge/response password authentication succeeded
```

But I need to have only the username and not DOMAIN+username, because I use an NTLM module in apache that needs to have only the username.

I have `WinBind separator = +` into smb.conf, so I don't understand why I must retrieve my users with the domain and the + symbol.

Answer (score 2):

You should have posted config of /etc/samba/smb.conf

Anyway, within that file, pls add this line under the block [global]:

```
[global]
winbind use default domain = true
```

then restart winbindd service